# Two-way bind some properties of two distinct scopes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have two distinct scope and i wan't to two-way bind some properties of those scopes together.

Is there any function in angularJS API to perform this, or i must write it on my own ?

```
var scope1 = $rootScope.$new();
var scope2 = $rootScope.$new();

bind(scope1, 'attr1', scope2, 'attr2');
// bind() This is the function i'm looking for.

scope1.attr1 = 'foo';
$rootScope.$digest();
// scope1.attr1 === scope2.attr2 === 'foo'

scope2.attr2 = 'bar';
$rootScope.$digest();
// scope2.attr2 === scope1.attr1 === 'bar'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Ctrl($rootScope) {

  function bind(scope1, attr1, scope2, attr2){

    var l1 = scope1.$watch(attr1, function () {
        scope2[attr2] = scope1[attr1];
    });

    var l2 = scope2.$watch(attr2, function () {
        scope1[attr1] = scope2[attr2];
    });

    scope1.$on('$destroy', onScopeDestroy);
    scope2.$on('$destroy', onScopeDestroy); 

    function onScopeDestroy(){   
      l1();
      l2();
    }

  } 

  var scope1 = $rootScope.$new();
  var scope2 = $rootScope.$new();

  bind(scope1, 'attr1', scope2, 'attr2');

  setTimeout(function() {
    scope1.attr1 = 'foo';
    $rootScope.$digest();
    // scope1.attr1 === scope2.attr2 === 'foo'
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    scope2.attr2 = 'bar';
    $rootScope.$digest();
    // scope1.attr1 === scope2.attr2 === 'bar'
  }, 2000);

}
```

I used timeouts to avoid make $digest when $rootScope it's in $apply phase. I did it using $watchers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. So there's nothing in API to do this ... What if scope2 is destroyed ? Won't it cause a memory leak ?

Comment: I didn't find something similar in API. And yes you're right, this code will cause a memory leak, I will edit it to avoid a memory leak.